# how to add multiple rows into single response to client using PHP

Tags: php, service, response

I am trying to pass multiple rows from database to client as response, but I can't achieve it! `Error: {"src":null, "dest":null}` like this, but if i tried to `echo` the `$s` value there inside it prints the column values but its not passing.

Here is my code.:

```
$c=$db->getcount($dest);
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($dest);

if ($user != false) {
    $response["success"] = 1;

    for($j=0;$j<=$c;$j++) {
        $s= $user[$j]['src'];
        $d =$user[$j]['dest'];

        $response["user"]["src"] = $s;
        $response["user"]["dest"] = $d;  
    }

    echo json_encode($response);  
}
```

Comment: it appears you are overriding $response["user"][...] at each iteration.

Comment: also, you are testing j<=c, while you should be testing j<c

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $response["user"][]["src"]= $s;
  $response["user"][]["dest"]= $d;
```

Instead of

```
  $response["user"]["src"] = $s;
  $response["user"]["dest"] = $d;
```

Comment: or you can
$response["user"][] = array("src"=>$s,"dest"=>$d);

Answer (score 0):

it appears you are overriding $response["user"][...] at each iteration:

```
$response["user"][] = array(
    "src" => $user[$j]['src'],
    "dest" => $user[$j]['dest'],
);
```